# WPF control extra pixels source

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, grid, stackpanel

I have these simple `wpf` controls in this layout. My question where is the extra pixels coming from in the `TextBox`. It looks like the `TextBox` is not respecting the `Width='Auto'` property.

I'm looking to make the Grid Column 0 width equal exactly to the width of the TextBox.

[image of rendered code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYtzd.png)

```
 <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="This TextBox located in Row 0 Column 0"
                     Width="Auto"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                 Text="This TextBox located in Row 1 Column 0 with Column Span of 2"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF's layout rules can be confusing at times, can't they? :)

The issue here is that you've set the width to `Auto` for both columns. `Grid` is only going to reduce the column width if it needs to or has a good reason to. Since you used `Auto` for the second column also, and since that column doesn't need to be increased in size to fit the longer second-row text, you get the sizes you see.

If you really want that first column to be as small as possible, set the *second* column width to `*` instead of `Auto`. (Or just omit the `Width` attribute…`*` is the default.)

Comment: Thank you. That was useful.